# How to use a neural network when there are many classes

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras-layer

We are using facenet and have generated embeddings (128 features) for faces https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet. We have 100k classes (celebrities) from MSCeleb http://www.msceleb.org/ and 8M samples.

How does one construct a neural network that can map the 128 features to 100k classes?

Using a fully connected layer would result in (128 + 1)*100k = 12.9 million parameters which seems too large to train.

Comment: the question is how many samples you have, not how many features, you aren't assigning a feature to a class but a sample to a class. The fact you have 128 features is completely fine, you just need to have enough samples to each class in order to start assigning classes based on the features

Comment: @Flika205 8 million samples. I think we have enough data. However multiplying 8 million samples by 12.9 million parameters sounds like years of training

Comment: You have a point in there, it will indeed take long to train this neural network model. What I would recommend is trying to look at a machine learning algorithm like Random Forest for example (and not a deep learning one) which doesn't require a big amount of epochs. But again, this is just an idea, it might not fit to your problem, but I believe it worth a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the FaceNet abstract:

> In this paper we present a system, called FaceNet, that directly
>   learns a mapping from face images to a compact Euclidean space where
>   distances directly correspond to a measure of face similarity. Once
>   this space has been produced, tasks such as face recognition,
>   verification and clustering can be easily implemented using standard
>   techniques with FaceNet embeddings as feature vectors.

Instead of training a classifier, consider doing a nearest neighbor search in the feature space. You can select anchor images for each of your 100k celebrities and then build a[k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) from their feature vectors. Then for each input you can find its nearest neighbor in the k-d tree.